# How do i randomize my answers, so that it syncs with the if else

Tags: python, random

i am trying to built a little game with random. In this game you have the choice to answer a question with "a1" and "a2" for "Answer 1" and "Answer 2". At the End it should print, if you chose the right Answer. To make it a little more dynamic i want that the Option for "a1" and "a2" is not always the same. Like the Answer, if the sky ist Blue shouldn't be always "a1". If would be nice if somebody helps me with my code.
Thanks

```
import random
from random import randint

list = ["a1", "a2"]
op1 = random.choice(list)
op2 = ""

if op1 == "a1":
    op2 = "a2"
else:
    op1 = "a2"


print("Is the Sky Blue ? If Yes type")
print("a1")
print("If NO type")
print("a2")

test = "a1" # user input 

if test == op1:
    print("Yeah thats right")
elif test == op2:
    print("thats the wrong answer")
```

Comment: What is your *specific* question? "If would be nice if somebody helps me with my code" is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [ask], as well as [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't don't need to **from random import randint** because already you import random library.
2. if op1 == "a1", op2 == "a2", else: op1 will be "a2" and you need to add op2 = "a1".Because of you have 2 options in list.

And your code will be like this :

```
import random

list = ["a1", "a2"]
op1 = random.choice(list)

if op1 == "a1":
    op2 = "a2"
else:
    op2 = "a1"
     

test = input("your guess :")

if test == op1:
    print("Yeah thats right")
elif test == op2:
    print("thats the wrong answer")
```

Comment: Thanks ! i expanded it with the question choices and now it's working.

Comment: @dan969696 you are welcome. Good works.

Answer (score 0):

my Answer:

```
import random

list = ["a1", "a2"]
op1 = random.choice(list)
print(op1)
if op1 == "a1":
   op2 = "a2"
else:
   op2 = "a1"

 
print("Is the Sky Blue ? If Yes type")
if op1 == "a1":
   print("a1")
else:
   print("a2")
print("If NO type")
if op1 == "a2":
   print("a1")
else:
   print("a2")


test = input("your guess :")

if test == op1:
   print("Yeah thats right")
elif test == op2:
   print("thats the wrong answer")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).